# _UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem not called xcode 6

Tags: ios8, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode6, nsnotificationcenter

Is it just me or _UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem notification from uiimagepickercontroller stopped working on iOS 8 and XCode 6. I use it to rotate the camera overlay after the user taked a picture.
PLease help

Comment: im also looking for this answer please help us! And i do the same thing you do after capturing a photo

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty strange, but in iOS 8 setting observer using

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(imagePickerControllerDidCapture) name:@"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem" object:nil];
```

doesn't work for UIImagePickerController, but using block works fine:

```
self.imagePickerControllerDidCaptureObserver = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem" object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    [self removeCameraOverlay];
}];
```

Please notice that in this approach you should store observer object to detach it later using

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:imagePickerControllerDidCaptureObserver];
```

In situations like that it very useful to use

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:nil object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    NSLog(@"Notification: %@", note.name);
}];
```

to monitor all notifications, see names and moments it fires.

Answer (score 1):

I also see the same issue with iOS 8 but using block works as mentioned by [Amoneron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1838390/amoneron) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27567785/610106).

Here's how to do it in Swift:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem", object:nil, queue:nil, usingBlock: { note in
  // do something here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It still works for me, though I am using the notification center for that.

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver (new NSString ("_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem"), HandleUserCapturedItem);
```

the code is in c# as I am using xamarin to develop, there should be something similar in objective-c since I'm basically using wrapper classes (built by xamarin).