# How to know Camera Is completed taking taking picture In ios

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Im using image picker controller to present Camera,After image has been taken it’s entering into ending mode, So i want the delegate to call when camera is completed taking picture. 
Like by means of NSNotificationCenter .

```
       UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate=self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Implement the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` methods.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: This might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem" object:nil ];
```

Comment: You need to dismiss `picker`, not `self`.

Comment: No,This method is called when the image is selected i mean there are use and retake buttons, hen use is cliked this will be called, I want like nsnotiifcation to add observer when camera is completed taking picture

Comment: I changed the code above, you can register an NSNotification then implement your handleNotification method to do what you want

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392220/uiimagepickercontrolleruserdidcaptureitem-not-called-xcode-6 . May be this relevent

Comment: Thx,That is what Im looking for

Answer (score 0):

There is a delegate Method of UIImagePickerController .it has been called after taking picture.

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo :(NSDictionary *)info
```

Comment: No this method is calling when i Click in Use Image In editing screen